# Prove that if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ is convergent then so is $\sum a_n b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Prove that if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ is convergent and $a_n, b_n > 0$ then so is $\sum a_n b_n$.

I am aware that this question has been answered before. I am wondering if this specific proof technique works:

Let $\{s_n\}$ be the partial sum series of $\sum a_n b_n$. Let $\{s_a\}$ and $\{s_b\}$ be the partial sum series of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ respectively.

$(1)$ Since $a_n, b_n > 0$, then we know that $\{s_n\}$ is increasing

$(2)$ Since $\{s_a\}$ is convergent, for $s_{a_i} \in \{s_a\}, s_{a_i} \leq M$. Similarly, for $\{s_b\}$ there is an $N$ such that $s_{b_i} \leq M$. Hence we can conclude that $\{s_n\}$ must be upper bounded by $s_i \leq MN$.

By the monotonic sequence theorem, $\{s_n\}$ is convergent meaning that $\sum a_n b_n$ is also convergent.

Comment: Where does the “Since $a_n, b_n > 0$” come from?

Comment: You are right, I forgot to state this at the beginning

Comment: More is true.  If $a_n, b_n > 0$, $\sum a_n$ converges and $(b_n)$ is bounded, then $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.